# How does the additional "/" in the url address work in html? (ex:http://stackoverflow.com/questions*/ask*)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am confused on how the "/" works in htm ex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions**/ask**
So I have an api and how it works is that it looks up the username. So what I want is a search box and when they click search it goes to index.html/searchtext and in jquery it gets the "search" portion and turns it into a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current URL of the page in JavaScript by

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname; // Returns path only
var url      = window.location.href;     // Returns full URL
```

Once you have that you can use jQuery or pure javascript to get the last part of any URL or in your case the search text.

```
var url = 'http://www.website.com/index.html/searchtext'
var lastpart = url.split('/').reverse()[0];
```

Comment: Very helpful but whenever I type "/search" or any other text to the end of the url it ends up saying page not found.

Comment: If its `/search` the browser will consider that as a page name and will lookup for it in the server directory. However if u pass something like `/?search` the browser won't consider it as a new page instead it will load the same page again and you can then use JS to get the text.

Answer (score 0):

The magic is in the webserver, not your code.

This is done using url redirection or rewrite. For example, if you have an api that looks like this:

> http://example.com/user?name=USERNAME

In Apache, you'd create a mod_rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule  ^user/(.*)  user?name=$1
```

or in lighttpd you'd create a ModRewrite rule:

```
url.rewrite-once = ( "^/user/(.*)" => "/user/$1" )
```

In some languages such as node.js or go, web applications are more commonly implemented as web servers. Since the code is itself a web server you can specify rewrite rules directly in the routers.

For example in node.js with express we can write a handler as:

```
express.get('/user/:name',function(req,res) {
    var name = req.param('name'); // taken from the path
});
```

or in go we can write a route as:

```
router.GET("/user/:name", userHandler)
```

---

**Can this be done client side?**

Short answer: **no**.

Long answer: When the user keys in the url in the address bar and presses enter it's too late. You can intercept it with `.onbeforeunload` but redirects from `.onbeforeunload` are known to not work in most browsers. That is if you have your page open. If the user enters the address in a blank page you can't even intercept it.

Why this needs to be server side? Well, first of all, your page needs to load in order for you to run any javascript (for example to read `window.location`). In order to load you need a page for `http://example.com/user/slebetman` and another page for `http://example.com/user/armaiz` etc. But then if you have that you don't need to implement anything client-side.